# Passport.socketio: handshake is always unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I'm a Node-beginner and have the following problem. I use express, socket.io and passport as well as passport.socketio and a MongoStore.

I need to authenticate socket.io with passport (I use passport.socketio for this), but the handshake is always unauthorized even after successfull login. Here is my code so far:

```
var http = require('http')
var socketio = require('socket.io')
var express = require('express')
var stylus = require('stylus')
var passport = require('passport')
var passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
var mongo = require('mongoskin')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express)

var DB = mongo.db('mongo://127.0.0.1/accounts', {safe:false})
DB.bind('accounts')
DB.bind('SessionStore')

SessionStore = new MongoStore({ db: 'SessionStore' })


var app = express()  

app.configure(function () {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')
  app.use(express.cookieParser())
  app.use(express.bodyParser())
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'somekey',
    store: SessionStore
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())
  app.use(app.router)   
})
```

Here is where I login:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/login_failed',
                                                    failureFlash: false }))
```

And here I try to access a page ('/content'), for which I need authorization:

```
app.get('/content', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('content', { user: req.user })
})

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(5050)

var io = socketio.listen(server)

io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: express.cookieParser, 
  key:          'express.sid',        
  secret:       'somekey',  
  store:         SessionStore,      
  fail: function(data, accept) {      
  accept(null, false);              
  },
  success: function(data, accept) {
    accept(null, true);
  }
}))
```

But if a client now tries to access '/content', the server always responds 'handshake unauthorized':

```
// on client side
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5050'); 

// on server side
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) { 
  console.log(socket.handshake.user._id) 
}
-> handshake unauthorized
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's an issue known since two years and not resolve yet :

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/545

As koenigsbier said in this github issue :

> In my client side I had `var socket =
>   io.connect('http://localhost:8080');` and it's works only if you put
>   localhost:8080 in your browser.
>
> I changed it by `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');`
>   and now it works with localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080 in your
>   browser.
>
> It's clearly a bug, why socket.io should accept address mapping just
>   in one way? localhost is localhost and is the same as 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

On client side, try to put 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
key:          'connect.sid',
```

instead of

```
key:          'express.sid',
```

for the key.  Check out the cookie in your browser, you won't see express.sid, but connect.sid will have a value.  The only other difference that I see between yours and my working example is I set a var to express.cookieParser and then use that both in app config and in io.set authorization.

```
var cookieParser = express.cookieParser();
```